# Unzip protected file and execute exe file inside (using framework 4.0)

Tags: c#, winforms, unzip

Knowing i am using `framework 4.0`, i want to run an `exe` file who are inside a protected `Zip` file. I have the password of the `Zip` file.

Is there any functions or library under framework 4.0 can run an exe file who are inside protected zip file ?

Comment: you may want to take a look at this [SharpCompress](http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i Find the solution that make you can extract the protected Zip file.

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is a free, open-source library for handling ZIP files in .NET languages.

Dont forget to add the DLL to your references :

```
Ionic.Zip.dll
```

Add this line to your program :

```
using Ionic.Zip;
```

To extract protected file :

```
// extract all files into 
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read("archive.zip"))
{
    zip.Password= "SecretPassword";
    zip.ExtractAll("TargetFolder");
}
```

To run a EXE file inside your protected zip file, use this steps :

1. unzip your zip file in a Temp file
2. execute your exe file from Temp file
3. Delete Temp file